# How to make an extension work for several app targets?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS App target, open to everyone for the public store, all fine.
And I have 2 extensions with it in the project, including the bundle identifier in their identifier of that iOS App target.

Now I duplicated the first App target, added some changes, etc for B2B & MDM usage, but I want to use the same extensions, without having to change their bundle identifiers each time I change the build target, and I don't want to duplicate them as well with different bundle identifiers as well, if that is avoidable.

Visual example:
[image]

Basically I want to avoid delivering the code of the second target to the users of the first target, because after all, it is the minority who needs those changes.

I tried it with App groups, but that doesn't seem to help in any way.

Is there a way to make the extensions work for both App targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these option to you:

1.
You can duplicate the extensions, provide id from your developer portal, or let Xcode add them itself, and change the target identifiers to your new target.

2.
The other way is, to change the extensions bundle ids on build actions of the scheme to your currently required ones.
This could look somewhat like this, if you want to use PlistBuddy:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier fullBundleIdOfExtension" $PROJECT_DIR/Extension\ Directory/Info.plist
```

fullBundleIdOfExtension is something like com.company.application.extension

This way could cause errors sometimes on the build after a target switch, showing a dialog that the App could not be installed. This requires you to perform a clean build and rebuild.